# Add text to same line using sed

Tags: sed

How can I use a variable to find a pattern and then add a text, in the same line, after that pattern?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
sed -i "/$node_number/ i mytext" "$filepath.csv";
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. Please [edit] your question to include a minimal example of your input (CSV file) and desired output.

Answer (score 8):

This worked:

```
sed -i "s/$node_number/&mytext/" "filepath.csv";
```